# is there any multiple categories filter available in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I just want to setup categories filter based on selection. How to do this using WordPress function?

I have following steps need to follow

1. Choose Location (Can select multiple locations, for example fitness centre , cafe etc)
2. Select region (Can select multiple for example Fyn, The Capital)
3. Select region between (Can choose region between two areas)

4) Select Media Type (Can select multiple)

And need to show out results based on particular selection

Screenshot

[image]